# How Implicit Ordering[Option[T]] works in scala?

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm playing a bit with implicit resolution, and wanted to understand what this implicit val useful for ? In Ordering we have

```
trait OptionOrdering[T] extends Ordering[Option[T]] {
    def optionOrdering: Ordering[T]
    def compare(x: Option[T], y: Option[T]) = (x, y) match {
      case (None, None)       => 0
      case (None, _)          => -1
      case (_, None)          => 1
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) => optionOrdering.compare(x, y)
    }
  }
  implicit def Option[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[Option[T]] =
    new OptionOrdering[T] { val optionOrdering = ord }
```

I wonder when is implicit def Option[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[Option[T]] useful or called.

I tried the following:

```
def test[Option[T]: Ordering](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]]).compare(value1, value2)
}
```

But the compiler does not like it.

not found: type T
def test[Option[T]: Ordering](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {

and if i do which granted might not make sense but just for the sake

```
def test[Option[Int]: Ordering](value1: Option[Int], value2: Option[Int]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[Int]]).compare(value1, value2)
}

I get 

type Option takes type parameters
def test[Option[Int]: Ordering](value1: Option[Int], value2: Option[Int]) = {
No implicit Ordering defined for Option[Int]
```

Can someone give an example of how to use that implicit and or where is it useful and actually used ?

My assumption is that when there is a need of an Ordering[Option[T]] then this function is called to resolve the implicit. But i am not able to make that happen ....

**EDIT**
Well i wrote the following which make more sense

```
def test(value1: Option[Int], value2: Option[Int]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[Int]]).compare(value1, value2)
}
```

Then what i don't understand is the context Bound issue with

```
def test[Option[T]: Ordering](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]]).compare(value1, value2)
}

What's wrong with writing a context bound like that ?
```

Comment: Note that is quite weird to have that trait, usually, you would just implement an anonymous class in the body of the `implicit def`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder when is implicit def Option[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[Option[T]] useful or called.

Implicit methods can be used to construct type class instances out of other type class instances which can save boilerplate

```
implicit def Option[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[Option[T]] =
  new OptionOrdering[T] { val optionOrdering = ord }
```

For example given type class instance `Ordering[Int]` the above implicit method can construct type class instance `Ordering[Option[Int]]`. (Do not forget the `implicit` parameter, otherwise we get implicit conversion which is frowned upon).

> what's wrong with [Option[T]: Ordering]

The key is to understand the difference between type constructor and proper type. For example `Option` is a type constructor that can construct proper type `Option[Int]`. The type parameter clause `[Option[T]: Ordering]` in your definition

```
def test[Option[T]: Ordering](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T])
```

does not actually specify `Option` type constructor. It just happens that you named it the same however what you have specified is actually more like

```
def test[F[T]: Ordering](value1: F[T], value2: F[T])
```

Furthermore, `T` in `F[T]` cannot actually be used in the method parameter list, so in fact your definition is more like so

```
def test[F[_]: Ordering](value1: F[T], value2: F[T])
```

Now the errors should be clearer; `F[_]: Ordering` is requiring type class instance `Ordering[F]` where `F` is a type constructor however there are no such type class instances because the definition of type class `Ordering` is

```
trait Ordering[T]
```

where `T` is a proper type. Otherwise it would be defined something like

```
trait Ordering[F[_]]
```

An example of such a type class is [`Functor`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html)

```
trait Functor[F[_]]
```

Hence to syntactically fix your definition try something like

```
def test[T](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[Option[T]]) = {
  ev.compare(value1, value2)
}

test(Some(1), Some(42))
// res0: Int = -1

implicitly[Ordering[Option[Int]]].compare(Some(1), Some(42))
// res1: Int = -1
```

Here `test(Some(1), Some(42))` is equivalent to

```
test[Int](Some(1), Some(42))(Option[Int])
                                |
                         implicit method call
```

Comment: Yeah i agree with the error, i left it for history. I get the implicit that call an implicit parameter. No issue with that. Implicit resolution can be a val or a def that has only implicit parameters and return the type we want. This is ok, however, why can't I use a context bound instead of the explicit implicit parameter you did ?

Comment: I guess the question is more a context bound syntax, what's wrong with ```[Option[T]: Ordering]``` Why can't it be translated to ```implicit ev: Ordering[Option[T]]``` ?